の中では for emotions and thoughts?
''今後も本気で付き合っていくという証明のつもりだっただがきっと彼女の中ではそうではなかったのだろう。''
In this sentence how does one translate the ''の中では'' here? I feel it is very similar to 心の中では as if it is used for specific feelings or thoughts compared to の中に which seems to be more for physical objects. Let me know if I am wrong but that's just my theory.
Still, my main question is: Why では? and not には?
(And does ''彼女の中では'' translate to ''In her (mind)'' ?)

You are correct!


彼女の中では is usually synonymous with 彼女の心の中では. Of course, this is unless the context is about her immune system or something similar.
では is the correct particle choice because そうだ requires で, not に, as a location marker. In general, ～だ requires で.

ここでは私は父親ではなく学生だ。
Here, I am a student, not a father.



